# Basic bookmarklet help

Tags: bookmarklet

I want to create a bookmarklet that sets the page to be editable, that is, to run this code:

```
javascript:document.body.contentEditable=true;
```

When I made a bookmark of that, I could see that the page becomes editable very briefly and then the whole thing is replaced with the word "true".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bookmarklets have to evaluate to void for the browser stay on the same page. Just end it with a `void(0)`:

```js
javascript:document.body.contentEditable=true;void(0);
```

Answer (score 0):

After a bit of random trial and error, I found that this worked:

```
javascript:(function() { document.body.contentEditable=true; })()
```

Are there any other ways?

Comment: Anything where the last statement evaluates to `undefined` will work.

Answer (score 0):

Some sites suggest that you use `document.designMode=’on’`, but that doesn't work for me.

Regardless, your revised scripts works fine.